# Error loading src = ' ' when you click (ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I already have all I need to return JSON.
failure to do when you click the link for the item clicked it loads the video.
did all requests using jQuery, but I get an error that the page reloads. needs to be ajax, is possible?

jQuery:

```
var main = function () {
    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fac360%2Frss.xml'%20AND%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Fchannel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (json) {
            // titulos
            var titles = json.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
                return item.title;

            });

            // urls
            var urls = json.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
                return item.origLink;

            });

            $(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('</li><li>'));
            $(".container-list-podcast ul li").each(function (key, value) {
                var text = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<a class="link-podcast" href="' + urls[key] + '">' + text + '</a>');
            });


        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });


}(jQuery);

/// it is the problem...

$(document).ready(function () {
    var request = $(".link-podcast").attr("href");
    $('.link-podcast').click(function () {
        $('.video').attr('src', 'request');
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYwX3/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that are setting the `src` of your image to the string 'request'

```
$('.video').attr('src', 'request');
```

You will need to perform you ajax within callback of your `click` handler e.g.:

$(document).ready(function () {
    var request = $(".link-podcast").attr("href");

```
$('.link-podcast').click(function () {
  // pseudocode
  ajax ({
      success: function (result) {
         $('.video').attr('src', result);  // or result.url etc
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Those links are added dynamically, so what you're really looking for is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.container-list-podcast').on('click', '.link-podcast', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.video').attr('src', this.href);
  });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eYwX3/7/)